# screenshots programmatically in IPad with the image name

Tags: iphone, ipad

how to save the screenshot programmatically in Ipad with image name  taken from the user?

i've found a snippet which works but doesn't asks for the name of the image.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Also is it possible to create multiple folders in photo albums and save the image in it programmatically??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify a name when you save the image to the photo album. If you want to do that, you have to save the image to the app's directory folder and then build a way to show to the user, the images he has saved internally and allow him to delete, load, etc.

This is how to save a PNG image to disk

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myFileName];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);

[imageData writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
```

myImage is your UIImage and
myFileName is the name you want

Comment: Can you guide me how to do it??